# Swift: How to implement a custom AutoSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

In my iPhone project I have an unwind segue exiting to PlayView.
Inside unwind function as seen below I have a timer which delays for 0.05 seconds and then executes "autoSegue" function which in turn segues to other screens. This works fine on iOS 8 but for iOS7 devices, I am having to increase this delay significantly (up to 1.0 seconds), otherwise, it gives "another segue is already in progress" error.

Is there a way to execute "autoSegue" function automatically when any previous segues have been completed?

```
@IBAction func unwindToPlay (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    var del = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: "autoSegue", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your autoSegue from `viewDiDAppear` rather than from your unwind segue. This will only get called after all animation transitions are complete. You won't need a timer. But you may want to set some kind of flag in your unwind segue to trigger the action *only* after an unwind segue has taken place.

*EDIT*
As this doesn't seem to be working for you, here is some code...

```
class RedViewController: UIViewController {
    var segueDidUnwind: Bool = false

    @IBAction func unwindToRed(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        println("unwindToRed");
        segueDidUnwind = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        println("viewDidAppear");
        if (segueDidUnwind) {
            self.showVC()
            segueDidUnwind = false
        }
    }

    func showVC() {
        let vc =  UIViewController()
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It's an extension of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28381546/1375695) ... to which we can extend the logging...

```
actionForUnwindButton
prepareForSegue
unwindToRed
viewDidAppear
```

If `viewDidAppear` is not getting called in your code, you must have other structure to your project which is not apparent in the question.

Comment: viewDidAppear does not get called on unwind segue.

Comment: @Tpos, I must have misunderstood the structure of your project. I assume that the unwind segue takes you to "PlayView" (UIViewController), which should trigger `viewWillAppear` followed by `viewDidAppear` .

Comment: Your understanding is correct but since I am not removing PlayView after it is initially launched, it only calls viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear once at its initial launch. Subsequent unwind segues from other views to PlayView do not call viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear in PlayView. Unless I am doing something wrong which is causing that?

Comment: @Tpos, seems a bit strange to me. ViewWill / Did should  get called in 'normal' circumstances. Are you setting the navigationController delegate? Or using some container view controller setup?

Comment: My segues are modal type, perhaps thats y viewDidDisappear is not called for PlayView

Comment: @TPos, modal type makes no difference. But you should be looking for `viewDidAppear`, not `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: @fondry, yes viewDidAppear (typo)

Comment: @TPos, see my expanded answer

Comment: thanks for your detailed input. For some strange reason viewDidAppear was not being called on unwind segue on iOS 8 only. I worked around by checking for iOS version and implemented autoSegue in  viewDidAppear for iOS 7 as you suggested and for iOS 8 I left the code as is.