# Printing Variable Unwind Segue - Xcode 8.0 Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, unwind-segue

I want to print a variable when a bar button item (on the navigation bar) is pressed. When this bar button item is pressed an unwind segue will happen whilst a variable is set and then it will be printed to the console (log at the bottom of Xcode). This is my code:

```
    @IBAction func doneNavItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    textField.text = var variableUnwind

    print(variableUnwind)

}
```

I know that the unwind segue is being triggered before the variable can be printed from [How to do something before unwind segue action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380923/how-to-do-something-before-unwind-segue-action) but the solutions on here do not seem to work or I might be reading it wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move your variable setting code to the prepare for segue method.

```
@IBOutlet weak var testTextField: UITextField!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var variableUnwind = ("StackOverFlow")

        print(variableUnwind)
        let textContents = testTextField.text
        print(textContents)

    }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to set a variable based on what is in a text field?

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can simply create a outlet for the text field and access it in the prepare for segue method